# Comparing if value from one array exist in another with use of string comparing functions

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 comma separated values, which I convert in 2 arrays, named:
$companyCad and $programCad

Those 2 arrays return values in the following format:

**$companyCad**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 52.10
    [1] => 62
    [2] => 64.15.44.25
    [3] => 65.10
    [4] => 65.14
    [5] => 65.21
    [6] => 70
    [7] => 71
    [8] => 71.15.12
    [9] => 93.55
)
```

**$programCad**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 92.55
    [1] => 92.74
    [2] => 93
    [3] => 94.10
    [4] => 98.12
    [5] => 98.66
)
```

To compare if any of the `$companyCad` values exist in the `$programCad` I use the following code:

```
if (array_intersect($companyCad, $programCad)) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
   echo "Not found";
}
```

Above code return **not found** since 93.55 from `$programCad` is not found in the array `$companyCad`. I know that the code works just fine.

However I need partial match, that is:

If  the value of the `$companyCad` is longer than value of the `$programCad` for example `$companyCad[9] = 93.55` and the `$programCad[2] = 93` that should be considered as match.

If the `$companyCad[9] = 93.55` and the `$programCad[2] = 93.1` it should not be considered as match however.

If the `$companyCad[9] = 93.5X` and `the $programCad[2] = 93.5` it should be considered as match also. (X = any number)

Here are some more explanations of eventual format of the array values:

Array value will have at least 2 digits = XX
The shortest value may be XX while the longest is XX.XX.XX.XX
However it may end with 1 digit in some cases, example XX.X or XX.XX.X for example.

Any idea how can I do this partial match?

Comment: What's the logic in indexes 2 and 9? Why not 4 and 7 or 5 and 1?

Comment: To understand correctly, your array values are String right ?

Comment: Yes, the values are string

Comment: @u_muldeer There is no logic. It just happen to be index 2 and 9, it may be any two indexes.

Comment: Why is `93` considered match but `93.1` not?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois when it is 2 digits only, means all that starts with 93 is match. However, if the value is 93.1, that mean anything that starts with 93.1 is match. So the match for the 93.1 will be anything that looks like 93.1X.XX.XX (X may be any number)

Comment: To understand correctly again, you want 93.55.40 and 93.55 be match but 93.55.40 and 93 isn't just like 93.55.40 and 93.54 isn't too, am i right?

Comment: @ErolKESKİN 93.55.40 and 93.55 is match. 93.55.40 and 93 is match.93.55.40 and 93.54 is not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish it is using nested loops and [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) to look if the haystack (value from first loop) starts with the needle (value from second loop).

```
$companyCad = array("52.10", "62", "64.15.44.25", "65.10", "65.14", "65.21", "70", "71", "71.15.12", "93.55");
$programCad = array("92.55", "92.74", "93", "94.10", "98.12", "98.66", "71.1");

$found = false;
foreach($companyCad as $comp) {
    foreach($programCad as $prog) {
        if(strpos($comp, $prog) === 0) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if($found === true) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/2mSrj)

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is here.

```
$fileOfArray = array("52.10", "52", "65.10");
$matchOfArray = preg_grep("/52/", $fileOfArray);
```

Output is `52.10`

Also look into this [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

Comment: Can you give an example how this code snipped will work using the code and values that I have above? I am struggling to understand how to use this code...I am looking the documentation now...

Comment: @user2417624 Like [this](https://3v4l.org/ELDb4), but it's slower than nested loops.

Comment: Thank u @CharlotteDunois for live demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [array_uintersect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) like so:

```
$matches = array_uintersect($companyCad, $programCad, function($a, $b) {
    // Compare $a and $b
});
```

I've run out of time in creating a comparison algorithm. Here is a half finished one:

```
    // Split into components of number
    $a = explode('.', $a);
    $b = explode('.', $b);
    $aCount = count($a);


    // Chop off least signification digit when dealing with minor versions
    $a[count($a) - 1] = substr($a[count($a) - 1], 0, 1);
    $b[count($b) - 1] = substr($b[count($b) - 1], 0, 1);

    return (int)($a == $b);
```

I did consider this approach as well but explode is easier:

```
$versionA = preg_replace('/^(\d{2})(\.\d)?.*$/', '\1\2', $a);
$versionB = preg_replace('/^(\d{2})(\.\d)?.*$/', '\1\2', $b);
```

Comment: [version_compare](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) might come in handy if you get the versions to a stage where that function can accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that returns the matches in an array:

```
$result = array_filter($programCad, function($pcad) use ($companyCad) {
    return preg_grep("/^$pcad/", $companyCad);
});
```

Result for the sample data is:

```
Array (
    [2] => 93
)
```

The key (2) is the position in the original `$programCad` array.

If you are just interested in the *fact* whether there is a match or not, you can test it like this:

```
if ($result) echo "found";
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/630367).